# What is the most efficient way to get a specific link using Beautiful Soup in Python 3.0?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am currently learning Python specialization on coursera. I have come across the issue of extracting a specific link from a webpage using BeautifulSoup. From this webpage (http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html), I am supposed to extract a URL from user input and open that subsequent links, all identified through the anchor tab and run some number of iterations.

While I able to program them using Lists, I am wondering if there is any simpler way of doing it without using Lists or Dictionary?

```
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    nameList=list()
    loc=''
    count=0
    for tag in tags:
        loc=tag.get('href',None)
        nameList.append(loc)
    url=nameList[pos-1]
```

In the above code, you would notice that after locating the links using 'a' tag and 'href', I cant help but has to create a list called nameList to locate the position of link. As this is inefficient, I would like to know if I could directly locate the URL without using the lists. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to get an element out of `tags` list and *then* extract `href` value:

```
tags = soup('a')
a = tags[pos-1]
loc = a.get('href', None)
```

You can also use [`soup.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method to query `:nth-of-type` element:

```
soup.select('a:nth-of-type({})'.format(pos))
```

As `:nth-of-type` uses 1-based indexing, you don't need to subtract `1` from `pos` value if your users are expected to use 1-based indexing too.

---

Note that soup's `:nth-of-type` is not equivalent to CSS [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo-class, as it always selects only one element, while CSS selector may select many elements at once.

---

And if you're looking for "the most efficient way", then you need to look at [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
tree = fromstring(r.content)
url = tree.xpath('(//a)[{}]/@href'.format(pos))[0]
```

Comment: @ skovorodkin Thank you!